# Sufficient but not Complete statistics for binomial experiment

Tags: probability-theory, binomial-distribution, parameter-estimation, sufficient-statistics

Consider a binomial experiment with probability of success $p$ in which $m$ trials are
conducted resulting in $R$ successes. A further set of trials is then conducted until $s$ further
successes have occurred. The number of trials necessary in the second set is a random
variable $N$. Show that $(R,N)$ is a sufficient statistic for $p$, but not complete.

I know how to calculate a UMVUE for $p$ in a set of bernoulli trials, I reached $p^*=T/n$, where $n$ is the number of trials and $T$ is the sum of the observations. I know the definitions of sufficient, complete, UMVUE but not sure how to adapt it into something like $(R,N)$ as a statistic.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to MSE. Could you post your progress on this problem? What did you attempt? Some users do not answer assignment questions which have not been attempted at all by the student.

Comment: Hello. I know how to calculate a UMVUE for p in a set of bernoulli trials, I reached p^=T/n, where n is the number of trials and T is the sum of the observations. I know the definitions of sufficient, complete, UMVUE but not sure how to adapt it into something like (R,N) as a statistic.

Comment: Can you add this to the post?